# Submission Apple screenshots from IPA file

Tags: ios

Is there a way to generate all the previews for the Apple store submission from the IPA file.

Thanks

Comment: NO, it can be normally generated using meta data of app provided in iTunesConnect, something like smart banners do. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

Comment: Yes, have a look at [Fastlane](http://fastlane.tools). It will require you to do some setup, since it will need UI Automation to get to the correct screen. But then it will just run this for each device and create the screenshots. It can even do it for each language.

Comment: Going to check! Thanks guys!

Comment: Use the iOS simulator.

Answer (score -2):

Upload this iPA on Diawi.com, doing so you will got a link that will enable you to install your app in iphone and then you can take screen shots of your app.

Comment: The problem is that I have got the iPhone but not the iPad, neither iPad retina.

Comment: :) in that case you can resize your screen shot as your requirement or you can draw screenshots in PhotoShop.